# No output from simple program using System.out.println

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans, output

This has to be an easy question but can't seem to figure it out.  In Netbeans and in Eclipse I have successful builds but no output.  I'm thinking that there is something wrong with my JDK (possibly??) I can't post a screen shot:( so I'll  include the code.

```
package hiall;
public class HiAll {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("HiAll");
    }        
}
```

Can't get any simpler!!!

In HiAll(run)  window

---

run:
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)

---

Before I remove all java components and starting again does anyone have suggestions????

Comment: I'm not familiar with NetBeans but there should be some sort of a `Console` view, usually at the bottom. After/before running look for this view and select. Please note that this is just a guess. Your next step would be compiling and executing from the command line.

Comment: Are you sure you're actually running the program and not just building/compiling? If you're running this in a console window, it may exit before you even see the output -- try prompting for input after you print.

Comment: Maybe you are missing the Console view. Get some output you can see `while(true != false) System.out.println("hello mate, my name is output");` lol

Comment: How u r running the program? just right click the program select run as java application

Answer (score 3):

I had this exact problem in NetBeans (11.1) and the solution for me was to Clean+Build the project (Shift + F11). After that, running the project with F6 printed the expected output.

Answer (score 1):

I used to experience the same problem, I solved it using <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd> and then run <kbd>F6</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

In Netbeans there should be a so called "Output" Window in the down-right corner of your screen, which should show the console output (`System.out.println("");`).
Logically this does only occur, when you run the .jar-file by pressing "Run" (F6) (which is different from compiling or building [F11]).

[image: Netbeans]

If the console output is not visible, you can right click on the running process and select "Show Output"

[image: Show Output]

Answer (score 0):

Before remove anything, I'd try:

- Compile and run from command line using same JDK/JRE that is used in Eclipse/NetBeans. Does it print anything?
- As others suggest, make sure you are running the right class. Right-click on Java file: Run As->Java Application. Note that CTRL+F11, at least in Eclipse, runs last lauched, not the Windows that has the focus. So, it could not work if last program launched is not the class you are trying to run.
- Make sure you can see 'Console View'. If not, Menu->Window->Show View->Console View (in Eclipse).

Answer (score 0):

In the Projects panel on Netbeans (which should be the top left panel), right click on the class you're running and then press "run file".  You can open the output window by opening  Windows -> Output

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you go to 'Run' - 'Set main project' - 'none'.
Worked for me when i had the same problem.

Answer (score -1):

It outputs in your IDE's console, you won't see anything outside Eclipse
Look for the 'console' tab. In Eclipse it's in the bottom part of the screen (when you have default settings) . I don't know about NetBeans but should be similar.

If you expect a screen to pop-up and show you this text you could do this:

```
package hiall;
public class HiAll {

public static void main(String[] args) {
JFrame f=new JFrame();
JLabel label=new JLabel("HiAll");
f.add(label, BorderLayout.CENTER);
f.setVisible(true);
f.setSize(400,400);
}        
}
```

Comment: NetBeans too has a Console window at the bottom with an `Output` tab in the bottom left of the IDE.

Comment: OPs code should work, too. 
Your code doesn't solve the problem, but shows the text in the GUI.